# how to get all the documents that are matching the fields in mongodb using mongoose by using search operation with multiple fields in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, search

`

```
const getCandidates = (req,res,next) => {
    console.log(req.params);
    
    Candidate.find({
       $or:[
        {"name":req.params.name},
        {"email":req.params.email},
        {"role":req.params.role},
        {"status":req.params.status}
       ]}
      ,
      function(err, result) {
        if(err) { console.log(err);
                  throw err;
        }
        res.json(result);
      });
}
```

`

I want all the documents which matches the fields, the user may or may not give all the fields to search and retrieve.

Comment: what issue you face with that approach. It seems to be fine

Comment: I am getting all the documents that are not matching

Comment: try with email and name only and debug the results

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem occurs because you are using the `$or` this makes it so one filters for instance the `name` with a value, but then it does an or on the `email` field which if empty just returns all the documents, I think you need some logic to check if a value and if it is empty not return it and I think for your use case you do not need the `$or`, I did this in my application like this:

```
const query = Object.entries(req.params.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (value !== "") {
        return { ...acc, [key]: value };
    }
    return acc
, {});

const result = await Candidate.find(query);

res.json(result);
```